# Regex named group empty

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

This is my program:

```
 class Program
    {
        private static Regex _regex = new Regex("<span id='TotalG'>$ (?<amount>.*?)</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");

            var match = _regex.Match(text);

            var group = match.Groups["amount"];

          //  Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

The text does contain this text:

```
<td align="right" bgcolor=c0c0c0 style="font-weight:bold"> <span id='TotalG'>$ 0.00</span></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

yet the named group is always empty. Any idea why would this happen?

Comment: your regex doesn't even match,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the `$`, `<` and `>` by adding a backslash before it.

And I would actually suggest a different regex for the named group as well:

```
"\\<span id='TotalG'\\>\\$(?<amount>[^\\<]*)\\</span\\>"
```

I'm pretty sure that `>`'s and `<`'s should only be escaped when in (parenthesis), but I rather escape stuff instead of remembering regex rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing `html` you can use help of [Html agile pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.html");
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='TotalG']");
if (node != null)
{
    var temp = node.InnerText;
}
```